# Convert 'intercept/drift' term to 'constant' term in arima/auto.arima functions, in case of higher orders - R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, intercept

suppose for a time series, the auto.arima output is:

```
ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1  intercept
      0.7456  0.2775   767.7463
s.e.  0.0804  0.1197     0.1072
```

It is specified in help file of arima function that definition used for this function is

```
X[t] = a[1]X[t-1] + … + a[p]X[t-p] + e[t] + b[1]e[t-1] + … + b[q]e[t-q]
```

and if we include mean(m),  this formula applies to X - m rather than X.

My questions are:

**(1)  For the model considered above, what will be the arima equation?**

```
  (a) X[t] =  767.7463 + 0.7456*X[t-1] + 0.2775*e[t-1]
```

or    `(b) X[t] =  195.3258 + 0.7456*X[t-1] + 0.2775*e[t-1]`,

where constant term is achieved by 195.3258 = 767.7463*(1-0.7456).

**(2) How to interpret this constant term if we have more than one AR coefficient?**

```
e.g. ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2  intercept
      -0.0124  -0.6945  0.3629  0.9414    -0.1288
s.e.   0.1172   0.1132  0.0598  0.1270     0.0636
```

**(3) What should be the ARIMA equation in presence of drift term?**

```
e.g. ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1   drift
      0.3307  0.3981
s.e.  0.0946  0.1463
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The model with no differencing:**

$$\phi(B)(X_t -c) = \theta(B)e_t$$
where $\phi(B)=1-\phi_1B - \cdots - \phi_pB^p$, 
$\theta(B)=1+\theta_1B + \cdots + \phi_pB^p$,
and $c$ is the "intercept".

**The model with differencing:**

$$\phi(B)(1-B)(X_t -ct) = \theta(B)e_t$$
where $c$ is the "drift" parameter.

**Example 1:**
$$(1-0.7456B)(X_t - 767.7463) = (1+0.2775B)e_t$$
So
\begin{align*}
X_t &= (1-0.7456)*(767.7463)  + 0.7456*X_{t-1}  + e_t + 0.2775 e_{t-1} \\
    &= 195.3147  + 0.7456*X_{t-1}  + e_t + 0.2775 e_{t-1} 
\end{align*}

**Example 2:**
$$(1+0.0124B + 0.6945B^2)(X_t +0.1288) = (1+0.3629B + 0.9414B^2)e_t$$
So
\begin{align*}
X_t &= -(1+0.0124 + 0.6945)*(0.1288)  - 0.0124 X_{t-1} -0.6945 X_{t-2} + 0.3629 e_{t-1} + 0.9414 e_{t-2} + e_t\\
   &= -0.2198 - 0.0124 X_{t-1} -0.6945 X_{t-2} + 0.3629 e_{t-1} + 0.9414 e_{t-2} + e_t
\end{align*}

**Example 3:**
$$(1-0.3307B)(1-B)(X_t - 0.3981t) = e_t$$
So
\begin{align*}
X_t & = (1-0.3307)*0.3981 +  1.3307X_{t-1} - 0.3307 X_{t-2} + e_t \\
 & = 0.2664 +  0.3307X_{t-1} - 0.3307 X_{t-2} + e_t 
\end{align*}

Comment: In the model with differencing, is the drift parameter ct multiplicative? That is, were I forecasting t + h periods in the future, would I get the appropriate drift value with c*(t + h)?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question 1, what ARIMA calls the intercept is in reality the estimated mean of the time series. So the obtained constant term

195.3258 = 767.7463*(1-0.7456)

is the estimated intercept.
See issue 3 in http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/Rissues.htm for an example: